# Unknown angular error when using sorting directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular directive that sorts columns in a table. prior to version 1.20 this worked but after upgrading to 1.20 I am getting the following error. Does anyone know what is wrong?

> Error: [$parse:isecprv]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/isecprv?p0=_sort()

```
app.directive('sorted', function () {
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a href="#/" ng-click="_sort()" ng-transclude=""></a>' +
            '<span class="sortArrow" ng-show="show_sort_icon(true)">&#x25BC;</span>' +
            '<span class="sortArrow" ng-show="show_sort_icon(false)">&#x25B2;</span>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            $scope._sort = function () {
                $scope.model.sort($attrs.sorted);
            };

            $scope.show_sort_icon = function (is_desc) {
                return ($scope.model.sidx == $attrs.sorted) && ($scope.model.is_desc == is_desc);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Usage:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th sorted="something">Something</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in model.items">
            <td>{{item.something}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: can you reproduce this error in Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: @MaximShoustin i'll try and post back.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle. One question: Why you dont use the orderBy Filter? What is the advantage

Comment: Thanks guys not sure what the problem was but in trying to reproduce in fiddle i found 1.2.1 works fine.

Comment: PS - the reason i need to filter on the server is because the client receives a subset of the full results. sorting needs to occur on the full set.

Comment: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/error/$parse:isecprv

Comment: Reverted here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4ab16aaaf762e9038803da1f967ac8cb6650727d

Comment: Good find @Heikki. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found by @Heikki

> Fields with names that begin or end with an underscore are considered
>   private fields. Angular expressions are not allowed to reference such
>   fields on the scope chain. This only applies to Angular expressions
>   (e.g. interpolation and calls to $parse with a string expression
>   argument) – Javascript itself has no such notion.
>
> To resolve this error, use an alternate non-private field if available
>   or make the field public (by removing any leading and trailing
>   underscore characters from its name.)
>
> Example expression that would result in this error:

```
<div>{{user._private_field}}</div>
```